# concatenate column using derived column in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have asked this question before and I believed to have got the correct answer but i didnt.

What I am trying to achieve is `Column 5`:

```
Column 1 Columns 2 Column 3 Column 4  Column 5
A        B         NULL      D         A|B|D
B                  C                   B|C
NULL     D         NULL     NULL       D
```

I used a derived column:

```
(DT_STR,50,1252)((Column1 == "" ? "" : Column1 + "|") + (Column2 == "" ? "" : Column2 + "|") +   (Column3 == "" ? "" : Column3 + "|") + (Column4 == "" ? "" : Column4))
```

But I ended with:

```
Column 1 Columns 2 Column 3 Column 4  Column 5
A        NULL      NULL      D        NULL
```

If I get NULL the overall answer is NULL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate columns using derived column in ssis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597737/concatenate-columns-using-derived-column-in-ssis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(DT_STR,50,1252)((Column1 == "" || isnull(Column1) ? "" : Column1 + "|") + 
                 (Column2 == "" || isnull(Column2) ? "" : Column2 + "|") +   
                 (Column3 == "" || isnull(Column3) ? "" : Column3 + "|") + 
                 (Column4 == "" || isnull(Column4) ? "" : Column4))
```

Answer (score 0):

===
Hi Try using

```
ISNULL(Value) ? " " : Value
```

for each column

Mario